# ASF Streaming on Android?

Tags: android, stream, asf

I am currently testing if it is possible to write an Android app that shows the stream of my IP webcam (Foscam Fi8918w). I know that there are some apps that are able to do that, but that apps do not have the functionality I need.

By analysing the cam I found an ASF Stream with two streams embedded:

Stream 1: Motion JPEG Video (MJPG) at 640*480

Stream 2: IMA WAV ADPCM Audio (8000Hz, 16bit Mono)

Then I searched Google for Android ASF instructions without any results. The only thing I found was Android media player does not support it.

Wikipedia had a link with the [ASF specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/0/790fecaa-f64a-4a5e-a430-0bccdab3f1b4/ASF_Specification.doc), so it's no magic behind that. Is there really no other way to do it than implement everything by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [RockPlayer [Lite Version, Free]](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified.lite&hl=en). Unlike most other media players including the stock one, it implements software decoding so supports more formats.

I don't know if it will decode your ASF stream but since it's free, give it a try. If not, I've emailed the developers a couple of times with ideas which were integrated - They may well be willing to add support if you contact them.

Comment: This will not solve my problem, as i do not want to show the video content of my stream, but only playback the audio. Even this should be passed through some filters, so i will have to write my own app. I just would need a ASF filter...