# Streaming .asf on android

Tags: java, android

I have FOSCAM FI8918W that returns live video+audio stream in .asf format. I want to build an app for android that streams this video on android phone. I just don't know how and where to start. I have done a lot of googling on this but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Similar question was asked here 2 years back but received no significant replies (link - [ASF Streaming on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418513/asf-streaming-on-android)).

regards

Comment: Well, what I know from my limited knowledge is that there is no direct way. You will have to implement a transcoder. Android does not support `ASF` format. Instead, you will have to store the `ASF` data locally and then convert it to a format Android supports

Answer (score 1):

Generic Android (AOSP) supports very limited set of codecs and containers - see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Some devices do support additional codecs/containers, but as non-standard extension. ASF with MJPEG stream is not supported by AOSP.

But it shouldn't be too hard to implement it in the user mode - this is a camera, so you don't need to worry about stream position (for seek and rewind) and MJPEG is simple to decode and display. Just read the stream and display as a sequence of frames.